# no wired connection after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, internet, ethernet, 16.04

After upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 (64bit both), I can no longer establish a wired connection to the internet. I am using a desktop PC without wireless card, so I am relying on ethernet. The cable works as I had internet connection during the upgrade and only lost it after I rebooted once the upgrade was complete. Full disclosure: I have been using Ubuntu for a few months only so I am not very versed in it.

`ifconfig -a` gives the following output:

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8c:89:a5:xx:xx:xx 
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea6:251d:95dd:dea0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:26388 (26.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:86432 (86.4 KB)  TX bytes:86432 (86.4 KB)
```

and `ip link` gives me this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:89:a5:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`
```

I tried to solve the issue by doing the following:

first, I renamed the ethernet connection to eth0 by creating

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules
```

and adding the line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="8c:89:a5:xx:xx:xx",KERNEL== "enp2s0", NAME="eth0"
```

then, I edited network interfaces

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

by adding

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

These measures did not help.
Neither did

```
sudo ethtool -s NAME speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

with NAME = enp2s0 before and eth0 after renaming.

Since nothing worked I reverted everything back to the original state and hope that some of you might have a better idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, your network card has not any IP address asigned, maybe the DHCP is not working correctly. Try to use fixed IP address and see if the problem continues. Then we can try to solve the DHCP problem (if it exists)

Comment: Assigning a fixed IP address indeed solved the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: So it looks like a DHCP issue. You should look for information about that, maybe is a bad configuration on your PC or maybe the problem is in your router.

Comment: I suspect that the issue stems from my PC since it arose with the upgrade and my laptop still gets its ip address dynamically assigned. I tried `dhcping` and received _no answer_ as a response

Comment: That's good, now you know where the problem is. Look for information on how to correctly configure a network interface with DHCP, I can't help you with this, sorry.

Comment: no worries, you helped me a lot already.Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this I've just changed the reference from eth0 to enp2s0 (or what ever your interface is named) in `/etc/network/interfaces`.  There may be a better way but it worked.